# Calculating voltage of a circuit with changing current

Tags: circuit-analysis, batteries, dc, python

I'm taking a class about batteries and circuits, and I'm trying a bunch of practice problems in Python. I'm having trouble solving for the voltage of a battery's circuit:

[image: circuit diagram]

I am given that, with a straightforward application of Kirchhoff's voltage law, that the cell's voltage can be modeled as:

(1) \$V(t) = V_{OC} - R_{1}\cdot I_{R1}(t) - R_{cell}\cdot I(t)\$

where \$V_{OC}\$ corresponds to a constant open-circuit voltage and the current running through the main outer circuit \$I(t)\$ is controlled and changing over time. In this problem, I am given \$V_{OC}\$, \$R_{1}\$, \$R_{cell}\$, \$C_1\$, and \$I(t)\$, so I believe the problem really amounts to calculating \$I_{R1}(t)\$. Based on some research I did online, I found that \$I_{R1}(t)\$ can be calculated as:

(2) \$I_{R1}[k+1] = exp(-\Delta t/R_1C_1)I_{R1}[k] + (1 - exp(-\Delta t/R_1C_1))I[k]\$

However, when I tried implementing these equations (see code and result below), I'm completely unsure if I'm getting something that makes sense:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# write a function that returns the battery voltage
def battery_voltage(Rcell, R1, C1, Voc, current, dt):

    voltage_values = [Voc]
    capacitor_current = 0.0

    #adding time constant calculation here
    tau = R1*C1

    #calculate voltages over time
    for i in range(len(current)):
        capacitor_current = np.exp(-dt/tau)*capacitor_current + (1 - np.exp(-dt/tau))*current[i]
        voltage_rc = R1*capacitor_current
        voltage_new = Voc - Rcell*current[i] - voltage_rc

        voltage_values.append(voltage_new)

    return voltage_values

#come up with a test case and plot the result
dt = 1
current = [0]*3+ [-10]*50+[0]*200

Rcell = 1.5e-2 #Ohms
R1 = 2.5e-2 #Ohms
C1 = 1.3e3 #Cap
Voc = 3.2 #Volts

#output from function above
out = battery_voltage(Rcell, R1, C1, Voc, current, dt)

plt.plot(out)
plt.title('Result for self-check')
plt.xlabel('Time (Seconds)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm having a hard time intuitively understanding what kind of behavior I should expect from the circuit given the inputs I have, so I have no idea if I'm on the right track. Can someone let me know if my solution/implementation is correct and how to interpret the behavior?

Comment: I'm unsure what voltage you are trying to calculate.

Comment: That would be the voltage across the +/- terminals on the right side of the diagram, which I labelled Vbatt. I just realized I didnt use the same name in my equation so I'll update it now, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: That voltage will be identical to the battery voltage at all points in time in the schematic you have provided.

Comment: OK, I guess I'm not relaying the problem properly (and that means I probably dont understand it too well myself). The point is that a cell's voltage drops when it is under load, and its dynamics can be modeled as an ideal voltage source that is placed in series with a resistor and a parallel RC circuit as shown in the diagram. The new cell voltage, V(t), can apparently be calculated with equation 1, which I am asked to solve for, but I guess Im not sure where that measurement is made exactly

Comment: Your schematic shows no loading resistor <-- that's the problem as I see it.

Comment: Strange, I copied the schematic exactly as is. I guess I'm not sure what exactly is going on here anymore. The problem already gives me equation 1, which does seem to be based on the schematic, so I assumed that it made sense.

Comment: This isn't all that clear.  Define the load, and then revisit.  You can't know the currents until you know the load.  Don't even try

Answer (score 1):

The plot starts with a positive charge, step current with a step voltage and an exponential rise.  This is followed by an equal discharge step current at 50 seconds followed by an exponential decay. Then it finishes with zero current.

There are two discrepancies

1. The plot shows programming +/- step currents from the right side, yet on the schematic, it’s labelled as a battery, which is just a voltage source (0 Ohm ideal) or sink. I see the whole circuit as a cell with a charger and load on the right over the short term of a few minutes.
2. Your plot looks like current steps sequentially of +10, -10, 0 but your program says in [?] as 0, -10, 0 for each time of 3,50,200 seconds.

What is missing is your statement of inputs and outputs in a list form. Then add a current generator to schematic where it says Vbat.

If I understand your program, it says;

```
   current = [0]*3+ [-10]*50+[0]*200
```

This schematic is a good start for a model of a battery cell if you have test experience , and seen this before.  The values might differ.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foYXpo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_4
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for the output voltage:

$$\text{V}_2=\frac{\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}\tag4$$

---

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (from now on I use the lower case letters for the function in the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)):

- $$\text{R}_2=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag5$$
- The input voltage is a stable DC voltage equal to \$\hat{\text{u}}\$, so:
  $$\text{v}_{\text{i}_1}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}\tag6$$

So, we get for \$\text{v}_2\left(\text{s}\right)\$:

$$\text{v}_2\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_4\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_3\right)\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_3\right)+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}\tag7$$

Using inverse Laplace transform, we can see that:

$$\text{V}_2\left(t\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\left(1+\frac{\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_4}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{C}\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_4\right)}\cdot t\right)\right)\tag8$$

Notice that:

- $$\text{V}_2\left(0\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_4}\tag9$$
- $$\lim_{t\space\to\space\infty}\text{V}_2\left(t\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag{10}$$

Using the example from your code, we get (where I choose a load resistance of \$\text{R}_4=100\space\Omega\$):

$$\text{V}_2\left(t\right)=\frac{8000}{50027503}\cdot\left(20003+5\exp\left(-\frac{40016t}{1300195}\right)\right)\tag{11}$$

[image]

I used the following Mathematica code to find the solutions:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
c = (13/10)*10^3;
R1 = (15/10)*10^(-2);
R3 = (25/10)*10^(-2);
R4 = 100;
u = 32/10;
R2 = 1/(s*c);
Vi = u/s;
FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[
  V2 /. Solve[{I4 == I1, I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, 
      I2 == (V1 - V2)/R2, I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, I4 == V2/R4}, {I1, I2, 
      I3, I4, V1, V2}][[1]], s, t]]

Out[1]=(8000 (20003 + 5 E^(-40016 t/1300195)))/50027503
```